# MediaPlayer generates 'can't play this video' error on Android

Tags: android, codenameone

I have a form that does nothing other than play a video that was downloaded from the server. It works fine, except that when pressing the back button (from the Toolbar or the device back button) after the video has finished playing, a native Android dialog with the message 'Can't play this video' pops up after the previous form already shows.  If I back out of the form while the video is playing I get no error.  I'd really like to get rid of this message.
Here's my code:

**The previous form**

```
final Button playVideo = new Button(res.getImage("play-video2.png"));
playVideo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            new VideoPlayerForm(getComponentForm(), (String) fileInfo.get("path")).show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

**VideoPlayerForm**

```
public VideoPlayerForm(Form instance, String videoUrl) throws IOException {
        super(instance);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE));
        setTitle(MyApplication.getInstance().getString("video"));
        String filepath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + MyApplication.DIRECTORY_APP_DOWNLOADS + "/" + videoUrl;
        try{
            if(!FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(filepath)){
                Log.p("Downloading " + videoUrl + " to local storage");
                success = Cn1FileUtils.downloadRemoteFile("https://medonline.co.il/uploads/" + videoUrl, videoUrl, true);                
                if(!success){
                    UniversalToast.show(MyApplication.getInstance().getString("error_video_download_failed"), UniversalToast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    return;
                }
            }
            final InputStream is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(filepath);
            video = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "video/mp4");
        }catch(Exception e){
            new DownloadedFileBrowserForm(this).show();
            return;
        }

        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new MediaPlayer(video));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onShowCompleted() {
        super.onShowCompleted();
        if(!success){
            previousInstance.showBack();
        }
        else{
            video.setFullScreen(true);
            video.play();
        }
    }   
}
```

**Android stacktrace**

```
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView: Unable to open content: file:///data/user/0/il.co.medonline.doctorapp/cache/mtmp-257887399
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1095)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1041)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:987)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:346)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:70)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:622)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:597)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:179)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2055)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
03-29 14:03:25.563 11427 11427 W VideoView:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
```

Comment: Before leaving from activity you should stop and release media player in onStop method of activity or fragment.

Comment: @chetanprajapat this is a codenameone project, there is only one activity

Comment: try : - add same in back button of toolbar or you should release player after video completion.

Comment: I actually already tried doing `video.cleanup()` in the back command, but it didn't help. Is there a way to trigger a callback on video completion?

Comment: If you are using media player then media player has onCompletionListener callback which will be called after complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think the full screen viewer incorrectly returns to your parent form instead of the actual back form (because of the full screen mode) and that triggers the start code again due to the `onShowComplete` method running twice.

You can get an event when the video finishes with this syntax:

```
video = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "video/mp4", () -> {
     video = null;
     parentForm.show();
});
```